# multiple select is not working :angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to select multiple value at a time using ui-select2 and for this i have added some angular-js script like

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angular-js/bower_components/select2/select2.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url() ?>angular-js/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url() ?>angular-js/bower_components/select2/select2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url() ?>angular-js/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url() ?>angular-js/bower_components/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js"></script>
```

and html code

```
<select multiple="multiple" ui-select2 ng-model="submitAdsFormData.city_id" ng-init="get_city_by_search()"  style="width:300px" required>
<option value="{{x.name}}" ng-repeat ="x in searchResult">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

For example, i want this type of select
https://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/rLmztr2d/  but in angularjs.

But not getting selected multiple value.can anyone help me to get this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to pass a JSON setup to  ui-select2 like

```
<select multiple="multiple" ui-select2="multiSetup" ng-model="submitAdsFormData.city_id" ng-init="get_city_by_search()"  style="width:300px" required>
<option value="{{x.name}}" ng-repeat ="x in searchResult">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and in a controller

```
$scope.searchResult = [{"text": "Group1", "id": 2}, {"text": "Group2", "id": 62}, {"text": "Group3", "id": 68}, {"text": "Group4", "id": 74}, {"text": "Group5", "id": 98}, {"text": "Group6", "id": 104}, {"text": "Group7", "id": 107}, {"text": "Group8", "id": 139}, {"text": "Group9", "id": 149}, {"text": "Group10", "id": 154}];
$scope.multiSetup = {
    multiple: true,
    formatSearching: 'Searching the group...',
    formatNoMatches: 'No group found'
};
```

working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dpX7jNkEgRoPyRZpJV92?p=preview).